# plot y-axis with the actual value from the hierarchical clustering in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to plot the dendogram by `Complete Linkage Method` in R.

I have the data set as:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
0,0.5,2.24,3.35,3
0.5,0,2.5,3.61,3.04
2.24,2.5,0,1.12,1.41
3.35,3.61,1.12,0,1.5
3,3.04,1.41,1.5,0
```

So far i have tried this code below and got the output as shown in figure:

```
dt <- read.csv("cluster.csv")
df<-scale(dt(-1))
dc<-dist(df,method = "euclidean")
hc1 <- hclust(dc, method = "complete" )
plot(hc1, labels = NULL, hang = 0.1, 
     main = "Cluster dendrogram", sub = NULL,
     xlab = NULL, ylab = "Height")
```

[image]

Now i wanted to

- plot y-axis with the actual value of the value generated from the 
     calculation of pairwise distances between clusters
- plot x-axis with the x1,x2,x3,x4,x5

How can i plot the graph using plot as i am learning R and got obstructed here.

**Edit:**

As mention on the answer i have edited the `labels` as

`labels = c("x1", "x2","x3","x4","x5")`

and got the output as:

[image]

**Now, i wanted to label the y-axis as the value calculated as the height**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access the values as below

```
dt <- read.csv("cluster.csv")
df<-scale(dt[-1])  # I had to use brackets here instead of parenthesis
dc<-dist(df,method = "euclidean")
hc1 <- hclust(dc, method = "complete" )
plot(hc1, labels = NULL, hang = 0.1, 
     main = "Cluster dendrogram", sub = NULL,
     xlab = NULL, ylab = "Height")
str(hc1)
```

Returns:

```
List of 7
 $ merge      : int [1:4, 1:2] -1 -3 -5 1 -2 -4 2 3
 $ height     : num [1:4] 0.444 1.516 1.851 3.753
 $ order      : int [1:5] 1 2 5 3 4
 $ labels     : NULL
 $ method     : chr "complete"
 $ call       : language hclust(d = dc, method = "complete")
 $ dist.method: chr "euclidean"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "hclust"
```

As you can see, there are no vectors with five values, which is what you'd need to map directly to `labels` in your plot. If you know how to compute those values, just put them into a five-element vector and place that after `labels =`, replacing the current `NULL`.

Comment: Awesome! One down. The y axis already has the height. The `height` vector is as follows: `num [1:4] 0.444 1.516 1.851 3.753`. So it ranges from around 0 to 4. That's what's on the y axis now. For greater detail, you might consider adding `abline(h = hc1$height, lty = 2, col = "lightgrey")`.

Comment: As the height measures in the dendogram are `num [1:4] 0.444 1.516 1.851 3.753`, but why while calculating on the paper the value are different? I have got the value as: `0.5, 1.12, 1.5, 3.61`

Comment: I'm lost on that. I've re-run it with the different methods for the distances (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html) and for the clustering (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/hclust.html), but the results were all higher than yours.

Comment: i will post this on the separate question! as i have got my answer for the above question.

Comment: Great! Consider Crossvalidated for that instead (more stats content)

Comment: Hey! can you help me to label the exact obtained value in y-axis line?

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult once you have created a five-element vector with the values (for the rest, see http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-text-to-a-plot-in-r-software). Sort of: `text(x, y, your_vector, cex=0.65, pos=3, col="grey")`